# Room; Store integer array to a separate table?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

Using `Room` ORM, I have declared an entity `EQPreset` using `@Entity` annotation. The entity contains an array `int[]`. It gives following error:

**error: Cannot figure out how to save this field (int[] arr) into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.**

Normally saving `EQPreset` instance to a database, I would create a separate table to store values of the array and have a foreign key pointing to the relevant `EQPreset`.
However, I need to find what will be the way of storing this `int[] arr` of `EQPreset` using `Room`, that is, either by making a separate table or using any good approach/way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option #1: Get rid of `int[] arr`. Have some other entity represent this integer, with a foreign key back to the `EQPreset` entity. Have methods on your DAO be able to give you the integer-entities for a given `EQPreset` entity.

Option #2: Use a `@TypeConverter` to convert the `int[]` into something that can go into a single column (e.g., convert it to and from a JSON array, represented as a string).